# @font-face not working in IE6

Tags: css, font-face

I have a font-face that is working across all my target browsers except for IE6

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'AFC-Bold';
    src: url('metaactionforchildren-bold.eot');
    src: url('metaactionforchildren-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('metaactionforchildren-bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('metaactionforchildren-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('metaactionforchildren-bold.svg#metaactionforchildren-bold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As you may know, IE6 only supports Embedded Open Type (EOT), so you might want to check if the CSS declaration is correct ― are the EOT's correctly linked?

Comment: @AeroCross I've just double-checked the links, and copied the file names over again to check i hadn't mistyped and they're all correct.  Thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 0):

It is not properly supported.

See: http://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface

Comment: The link you have provided indicates partial support meaning you have to include an eot which as you can see above I have - unless I have misunderstood the table.